# Background for radio button for Django form

Tags: css, django, forms, radio-button

I found some peaces of code solving the issue, but all of those are using input tag and label tag which placed near each other. Django forms placed input inside label, that's why the code is ineffective in my case.
One of variant I tried [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1vhbv2qm/)
Any advices or thoughts. 
Thanks all!

```
input[type=radio] {
display:none;
}

input[type=radio] + label
{
background: #999;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label
{
background: #0080FF;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue customized form template and applied the  solution on css above.

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% for item in field %}
        <input id="id_name_{{ forloop.counter0 }}" name="name" type="radio" value="{{ item.choice_value }}">
        <label for="id_name_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{ item.choice_label }}</label>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't check if my solution is right yet.
but you can write like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% for radio in field %}
    {{ radio tag }}
    <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}" title="{{ radio.choice_label }}"></label>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

For more information,
 you can read the official [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect).